# React render props pattern class errors

Tags: typescript

Help please.
it is assumed that the component can be used like this:

```
<MouseCoordinates></MouseCoordinates>

or

<MouseCoordinates>
    {(x,y) => { ... }}
</MouseCoordinates>
```

I don't understand what does it want.
Here is the code:

```
import React, { MouseEvent } from 'react';

const initialState = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const defaultProps = {
    children: (args: TMouseCoordinates) => null,
};

type TMouseCoordinates = typeof initialState;
type TDefaultProps = typeof defaultProps;

type TState = Readonly<TMouseCoordinates>;
type TProps = Partial<
    {
        children?: (coordinates: TMouseCoordinates) => JSX.Element;
    } & TDefaultProps
>;

class MouseCoordinates extends React.Component<TProps, TState> {
    static readonly defaultProps: TProps = defaultProps;
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    readonly state: TMouseCoordinates = initialState;

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

    handleMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
        const { screenX = 0, screenY = 0 } = event;

        this.setState(() => ({
            x: screenX,
            y: screenY,
        }));
    };

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        const isRenderIsFunction = typeof this.props.children === 'function';

        return isRenderIsFunction ? children(this.state) : null;
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

I have strange errors at:

```
static readonly defaultProps: TProps = defaultProps;
```

> Type '{ children: (args: { x: number; y: number; }) => null; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'Partial<{ children?: ((coordinates: { x: number;
>   y: number; }) => Element) | undefined; } & { chi...'.   Types of
>   property 'children' are incompatible.
>       Type '(args: { x: number; y: number; }) => null' is not assignable to type '(((coordinates: { x: number; y: number; }) => Element) &
>   ((args: { x: number; y: number; }) => nu...'.
>         Type '(args: { x: number; y: number; }) => null' is not assignable to type '((coordinates: { x: number; y: number; }) =>
>   Element) & ((args: { x: number; y: number; }) => null)'.
>           Type '(args: { x: number; y: number; }) => null' is not assignable to type '(coordinates: { x: number; y: number; }) =>
>   Element'.
>             Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.

here is cryptic error at:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
```

> "Argument of type '(event: MouseEvent) => void' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type
>   'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.\n  Type '(event:
>   MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type
>   'EventListenerObject'.\n    Property 'handleEvent' is missing in type
>   '(event: MouseEvent) => void'.",

and last

```
 return isRenderIsFunction ? children(this.state) : null;
```

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

Comment: What were you trying to do? What did you expect? Is this your own code or just code you've picked up from somewhere and tried to use (i.e. why is there code with ~3 independent errors in code you're writing)? Also, try to fix the title. **everyone** here is seeking help and tech belongs in the tags.

Comment: in `defaultProps` you have `children` as function returning `null`. In `TProps` you declare that `children`, if present, must also be a function that returns `JSX.Element`. But in reality it can't be both - that's what the first error is about.

Comment: @artem
but React.Element - it's a subset that includes null

Comment: The third error tells me that you are compiling with `strictNullChecks` turned on, if so then `null` as well as `undefined` values are excluded from every type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MouseEvent` should not be imported from React

Here is the correct code:

```
import React from 'react';

export type TMouseEventRenderer = (coordinates: ICoordinates) => JSX.Element | null;

const initialState = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const defaultProps = {
    children: (() => null) as TMouseEventRenderer,
};

type TDefaultProps = typeof defaultProps;
type TProps = Readonly<{ children?: TMouseEventRenderer } & TDefaultProps>;
type TState = Readonly<ICoordinates>;

class MouseCoordinates extends React.Component<TProps, TState> {
    static readonly defaultProps: TDefaultProps = defaultProps;
    readonly state: TState = initialState;

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
    }

    handleMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent): void => {
        const { screenX = 0, screenY = 0 } = event;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.setState(() => ({
                x: screenX,
                y: screenY,
            }));
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        const isRenderIsFunction = typeof this.props.children === 'function';

        return isRenderIsFunction ? children(this.state) : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type TProps = Partial<
{
    children?: (coordinates: TMouseCoordinates) => JSX.Element;
} & {
    children: (args: TMouseCoordinates) => null,
}>;
```

so you simple say: `children` props is required and not and contain both functions: `(args: TMouseCoordinates) => null` and `(coordinates: TMouseCoordinates) => JSX.Element` its simple has no sense.

i guess this is the interface you need:

```
interface Props{
    children?: (args: TMouseCoordinates) => (JSX.Element | null)
}
```

Comment: but I use to declare default props as it has been decsribed in doc

Comment: I'm not a novice in typing - I used Flow, but typescript's dances at default props is a little bit confusing

Comment: as described in docs default props should be declared in interface as optional and in defaultProps type it should be declared as required
If developer does not describe children in the component - component should not do anything -> render null.
But if children function is present - it should produce JSX.Element
In general - it's an option

Comment: I want to have children function optional, but have defaultProps.children to be present in case developer does not describe children function

Comment: so, how to in this case should I describe optional children prop?